# Unit Test Vs Exploratory Test in short term/long term scenarios

Tags: unit-testing, testing, exploratory

What do you think brings more value to the product, Unit Test or Exploratory Test?

I understand that both tests serve different general purposes, but what test would you prioritize, i.e. what would you do first and what second, Unit or Exploratory?

Also, which one pays more benefits in the short term? and in the long term?

Finally, would your answer change if you had only time for one of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion both are critical.  I follow a TDD methodology, so unit tests form an executable specification of my code.  Unit tests must be done first, but often in the process I find myself doing some forms of exploratory testing to create my passing unit test.  Further, there are somethings -- interface design, for example -- that cannot be fully developed without some form of exploration.  Yes, you can in many cases develop unit tests to ensure that interface elements operate the way they are expected to, but you often need to see how different elements *do* interact before you can determine how they *should* interact.  Exploring different scenarios and adjusting the test script based on feedback is an important part of the design.

For non-interface work, I would do unit tests first and exploratory tests as needed.   For interface work, I would prototype and explore, then develop unit (scripted) tests after, if at all.  This is partly due to the capabilities of test tools in each space, but that is related to the type of work being done as well.

As to benefits, it's hard to compare because they provide different kinds of benefits.  Both types of testing can find and eliminate defects, but unit testing (using TDD) guides and improves the design and structure of the application as well. By improving the design, we also improve maintainability. Exploratory testing, in my opinion, primarily improves the usability of the application, though it can be used to evaluate whether our design decisions actually work the way we expect and validate the design as it evolves.

My opinion is that unit tests are more foundational in that they provide a safety net from which all other tests can work to produce change.  In that sense they are more important, but you cannot do without either in a realistic environment.  Also, these aren't the only two types of testing, nor are they really directly comparable, in the same way as unit and integration tests are.  You can do unit tests that are explorations if you want using the debugger.

I can imagine scenarios in which you wouldn't have time to do automated, scripted tests but these are edge cases, at least for me.  I can't imagine a scenario where I wouldn't do some level of unit testing even if using manual, exploratory tests.  The application would have to be dead simple, indeed, before some level of unit testing isn't necessary.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed exposition. It is very interesting.

Comment: My case could be modelled as following; a functionality which enables the user to create a set of rules with boolean operators (AND/OR/NOT) and a series of parameter conditions (Param1 > x, Param2 == y, etc...). This is done with a module to create the rules, another module to define a set of actions if the rules are triggered, and an engine that would evaluate an object using the rules and launch the relevant actions if any.

Comment: I am trying to defend that developers taking the time to create the relevant unit tests before handing the functionality to QA pays more than just releasing it for test and rely on Exploratory Test for most obvious issues to come out. 

As I understand it, Dev should provide code that they are confident in at a Unit level, then QA will concentrate on the functionality, integration between units and so on...

Comment: Surely Dev should be confident at all levels - it costs more to find an issue in QA that in Dev

Comment: @EKI - developer-written, automated unit tests should be the norm.  Additional, scripted or manual QA tests (where you have a QA group) will not replace these.  Your automated unit tests will, in part, ensure that any changes you make in response to a failed QA test won't break something else.  Unit tests pay the most when written first as part of a TDD paradigm, IMO.